# Get Error WebPage Access is denied in IE

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, upload

I'm open file dialog with $('#dropbox').click
And then pick a file to upload . And then click button upload file in Firefox success file upload but in IE Get Error WebPage Access is denied(**line form.submit();**).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if((support.fileReader==false)&&(support.formData==false)){
$('input[type=button]').eq(0).attr("onClick",'fileUpload(this.form,"UploadHandler.ashx","upload");returnfalse;');
$('input[type=file]').eq(0).attr("onchange","fileSelectedIE();");
}
$('#dropbox').click(function(){
$('input[type=file]').click();
});
});
functionfileUpload(form,action_url,div_id){
//Createtheiframe...
variframe=document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.setAttribute("id","upload_iframe");
iframe.setAttribute("name","upload_iframe");
iframe.setAttribute("width","0");
iframe.setAttribute("height","0");
iframe.setAttribute("border","0");
iframe.setAttribute("style","width:0;height:0;border:none;");
//target="#fileIframe"
//Addtodocument...
form.parentNode.appendChild(iframe);
window.frames['upload_iframe'].name="upload_iframe";

iframeId=document.getElementById("upload_iframe");

//Addevent...
vareventHandler=function(){

if(iframeId.detachEvent){
iframeId.detachEvent("onload",eventHandler);
$('#progressNumber').text("100%");
}
elseiframeId.removeEventListener("load",eventHandler,false);
if(iframeId.addEventListener)iframeId.removeEventListener("progress",uploadProgress1,false);
//Messagefromserver...
if(iframeId.contentDocument){
content=iframeId.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
}elseif(iframeId.contentWindow){
content=iframeId.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
}elseif(iframeId.document){
content=iframeId.document.body.innerHTML;
}

document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML=content;

//Deltheiframe...
setTimeout('iframeId.parentNode.removeChild(iframeId)',250);
}

if(iframeId.addEventListener){
iframeId.addEventListener("load",eventHandler,true);
$('#progressNumber').text("Processing...");
}
if(iframeId.attachEvent)iframeId.attachEvent("onload",eventHandler);
//if(iframeId.addEventListener)iframeId.addEventListener("progress",uploadProgress1,false);

//Setpropertiesofform...
form.setAttribute("target","upload_iframe");
form.setAttribute("action",action_url);
form.setAttribute("method","post");
form.setAttribute("enctype","multipart/form-data");
form.setAttribute("encoding","multipart/form-data");
//Submittheform...
**form.submit();**

document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML="Uploading...";
}
functionfileSelectedIE(){
varfullname=$('#fileToUpload').val().toString();
varIndexExt=fullname.lastIndexOf(".");
varext=fullname.substr(IndexExt+1).toString();
varIndexFileName=fullname.lastIndexOf("\\");
varFileName=fullname.substring(IndexFileName+1,IndexExt).toString();
document.getElementById('fileName').innerHTML='Name:'+FileName;
document.getElementById('fileSize').innerHTML='Size:NotSupport';
document.getElementById('fileType').innerHTML='Type:'+ext;
}

<div id="dropbox"></div>
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload[]" id="fileToUpload" /></br>
<input type="button" value="upload"/>
```

What do I need in IE?

Comment: Same problem here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24189966/asp-net-web-forms-button-not-working-inside-iframe-in-ie9-and-below

Answer (score 0):

You cannot  pragmatically (via Javascript) click a file input element and then submit the associated form via Javascript.  IE will simply not allow this.  Your workflow is considered to be a security violation.  You will need to re-think your approach.